# Change Image with transition effects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following script that changes my image on a timer:

```
var da = setInterval( function() {

    var current_image = document.getElementById('node_picture').src;
    var image_index = current_image.substring(48,49);
    image_index++;

    if (image_index > 4) {
        image_index = 1;
    }

    document.getElementById('node_picture').src="img/node/<?php echo $node_id ?>/" + image_index + ".png";

}, 4000);
```

I am trying to add a jQuery FadeIn() effect. I tried to add

```
$('node_picture').FadeIn();
```

but that does not work.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note the case here:

```
$('node_picture').fadeIn();
```

http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

NB: All jQuery methods and properties use camel case with the initial letter in lower case.

---

When working with selectors, ids should be prefixed with the hash `#` symbol. I missed this the first time around, your comment made me take another look:

```
$('node_picture').fadeIn();  // wrong
$('#node_picture').fadeIn(); // right
```

http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

-- Unless that's also a typo? ;-)

Comment: I mistyped it in the original post, I used lowercase in the code, that's not the issue.

Comment: @Goro: Did you also mis-type the missing `#` symbol? see my updated answer.

Comment: Yes, I did miss that one. However, it doesn't seem to work with the has either.